# Inserting variable amount of rows based upon dates in range

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I have 4 variables:

```
@startDate
@endDate
@maxCourses
@preferredCourseStartDay
```

Let's say they're:

```
Start Date - 1st Aug 2016 
End Date - 30th Sept 2016 
Max Courses - 5
Start Day - Tuesday
```

.

I need to insert 5 rows in to a temporary table starting from the first tuesday in that date range.

sample output:

```
02/08/2016 
09/08/2016 
16/08/2016 
23/08/2016 
30/08/2016
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: please show sample output

Comment: 02/08/2016
09/08/2016
16/08/2016
23/08/2016
30/08/2016

Answer (score 2):

Here is one method that uses CTEs and window functions:

```
with n as (
      select row_number() over (order by (select null)) - 1 as n
      from master..spt_values
     )
select dte
from (select dateadd(day, n.n, @startdate) as dte,
             row_number() over (order by n.n) as seqnum
      from n
      where datename(weekday, dateadd(day, n.n, @startdate) ) = @preferredCourseStartDay
     ) x
where seqnum <= @maxCourses
order by dte;
```

I have no doubt that there is a pithy and elegant way to find the first Tuesday on or after a given data.  This method eschews that method and just looks for the Tuesdays in all dates that are generated.  Note that this assumes that your internationalization settings for the language.

Comment: I'm using azure and master..spt_values isn't supported, but I adapted this and got it working. Thanks for your response!

Comment: @Dough . . . This is just one way to construct a numbers table.  Any table will do as long as it has enough rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @startDate datetime = '8/1/2016'
declare @endDate datetime = '9/30/2106'
declare @maxCourses int = 5
declare @preferredCourseStartDay varchar(16) = 'Tuesday'

declare @wkDay int = case 
                        when @preferredCourseStartDay = 'Sunday' then 0
                        when @preferredCourseStartDay = 'Monday' then 1
                        when @preferredCourseStartDay = 'Tuesday' then 2
                        when @preferredCourseStartDay = 'Wednesday' then 3
                        when @preferredCourseStartDay = 'Thursday' then 4
                        when @preferredCourseStartDay = 'Friday' then 5
                        when @preferredCourseStartDay = 'Saturday' then 6
                    end



SELECT DATEADD(DAY,number+1,dateadd(dd,@wkDay - datepart(weekday,@startDate),@startDate)) [Date]
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE type = 'P'
AND DATEADD(DAY,number+1,dateadd(dd,@wkDay - datepart(weekday,@startDate),@startDate)) <= dateadd(day,@maxCourses,dateadd(dd,@wkDay - datepart(weekday,@startDate),@startDate))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the days are weekly or consecutive, below are examples of how to handle both scenarios.

```
DECLARE
 @StartDate  date        = '20160801',-- - 1st Aug 2016 
 @EndDate    date        = '20160930', --30th Sept 2016 
 @MaxCourses tinyint     = 5,
 @startDay   varchar(10) = 'Tuesday';

-- if you need the next 5 tuesdays
WITH 
E1(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) x(x)),
iTally(N) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))-1 FROM E1 a, E1 b, E1 c),
calendar(d) AS 
(
  SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY,@StartDate,@EndDate)) DATEADD(DAY,N,@startDate)
  FROM itally
)
SELECT TOP(@MaxCourses) d
FROM calendar
WHERE DATENAME(WEEKDAY,d) = @startDay;

-- if you need the next 5 days
WITH 
E1(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) x(x)),
iTally(N) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))-1 FROM E1 a, E1 b, E1 c),
calendar(N,d) AS 
(
  SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY,@StartDate,@EndDate)) N, DATEADD(DAY,N,@startDate)
  FROM itally
),
md(d1) AS (SELECT MIN(d) FROM calendar WHERE DATENAME(WEEKDAY,d) = @startDay)
SELECT TOP (@MaxCourses) d = DATEADD(day,N,d1)
FROM calendar CROSS JOIN md;
```